# how to get user GPS location while app in background on Android 8.0(Oreo devices) using service?

Tags: android, service, location, background-service

I want to get GPS location when the app in background, I have tried with services it will be working fine when the app in foreground and taking the locations, when the app goes to background it will stop the service automatically,
but I have tried with the same code below 7.0 devices it will be working fine. can anyone suggest me a good way to get the GPS location while app in background 8.0+ above devices?

Thanks!

Comment: use a foreground service if you want it to continue working in background

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko if we use foreground service it is possible to get the location more than an hour(1- 2 hours) continuously background?

Comment: Should be possible as long as the service is running. Another thing is that so long running location service will make the device battery run out fast

Comment: Okay will check, but some of the manufacturer who customizes native os like (oppo, vivo, xiaomi, samsung) they have a clear option so when service stops automatically even we start the service at foreground service is that any possible way to prevent this one?